# android volley: global variables does not change depending on the response on first time execution of method.

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-volley

I have method in which i am making a volley request and depending on the response I need to change a global boolean variable but for some reason the variable only gets changed after the method is executed completely giving me wrong data for the variable. I need to somehow changed the variable only after the response is recieved.. please help me with it

I need to change the value of variable 'chk' on response but it does not change.

```
  public boolean checkSourceCode() {

        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
        pDialog.show();

        final String entered_source_code = source_code.getText().toString();
        if(entered_source_code!=null || !entered_source_code.isEmpty()) {
            testString = entered_source_code;

            final StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String web_response) {
                    try {
                        response = new JSONObject(web_response);
                        Log.e("Resp SUCCESS", "" + response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        hasBeenValidated = true;
                        if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                            Log.e("Resp SUCCESS", "" + response);
                            validateCode = true;
                            chk=true; // THIS VALUE DOES NOT CHANGE ON FIRST CALL OF THE METHOD HOWEVER ON SECOND TIME CALLING THE METHOD IT CHANGED
                            //  Utils.reference_id = source_code.getText().toString().trim();
                            pDialog.hide();
                        input_layout_source_code.setError(null);
                        input_layout_source_code.setErrorEnabled(false);
                        Utils.reference_id = source_code.getText().toString().trim();
                        source_code.setBackground(source_code.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable());
                        } else {
                            validateCode = false;
                            chk=false;// THIS VALUE DOES NOT CHANGE ON FIRST CALL OF THE METHOD HOWEVER ON SECOND TIME CALLING THE METHOD IT CHANGED
                            pDialog.hide();
                        input_layout_source_code.setErrorEnabled(true);
                        input_layout_source_code.setError("Invalid reference Id.");
                        Utils.reference_id = null;
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid reference Id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    //    chk = validateSourceCode();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    String json = null;

                    if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        String strerror = "No internet Access, Check your internet connection.";
                        displayMessage(strerror);
                    }
                    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                    if (null != response && response.statusCode != 200) {
                        Log.e("Resp code", "" + response.statusCode);
                        displayMessage("Please contact administrator for error code " + response.statusCode);
                    }
                    if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                        switch (response.statusCode) {
                            case 400:
                                json = new String(response.data);
                                json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                                if (json != null) displayMessage(json);
                                break;
                            default:
                                json = new String(response.data);
                                json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                                if (json != null) displayMessage(json);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ) {
                @Override
                public Request.Priority getPriority() {
                    return Priority.IMMEDIATE;
                }

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> requestParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    requestParams.put("referral_code", entered_source_code);
//                params.put("email", "abc@androidhive.info");
//                params.put("password", "password123");

                    return requestParams;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Auth-Token", auth_token);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    60000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            // Adding request to request queue
            MaintainRequestQueue.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(sr, "tag");
        }
        else{
            pDialog.hide();
            chk=true;// THIS VALUE DOES NOT CHANGE ON FIRST CALL OF THE METHOD HOWEVER ON SECOND TIME CALLING THE METHOD IT CHANGED
        }
        Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(chk), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return chk;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

chk variable can not reinitialize again inside a thread
try this

setchk(boolean chk)

{
this.chk=chk;

}

and call it from request method;

Comment: hi, thanks for ur reply.. but this is not working :(

Comment: use debugger and analyse the code flow this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Your variable inside the volley request is not initialized by the time you reach: Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(chk), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  Use a get method to obtain the chk value within volley and call that getter where you need it.